# glibc detected double free or corruption (fasttop) using apache-tomcat6_0.43 And Cups

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, double-free

I have a  java web application running in sles 11 sp3
the application send pdf files to cups, sometimes application crash, and stop my tomcat service, the error is

```
INFO: Starting printing: 36199.pdf by Thread-2508
*** glibc detected *** /opt/jre1.6.0_31/bin/java: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000040a2f3e0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x76628)[0x7f28058e8628]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f28058ed5cc]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(CRYPTO_free+0x19)[0x7f27f0ed59e9]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(OBJ_NAME_add+0xa4)[0x7f27f0e965b4]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(EVP_add_cipher+0x20)[0x7f27f0eb91d0]
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8(SSL_library_init+0x16)[0x7f27f11a5596]
/usr/lib64/libcups.so.2(httpInitialize+0x5d)[0x7f27f1ece9dd]
/usr/lib64/libcups.so.2(httpConnectEncrypt+0x95)[0x7f27f1eceae5]
/opt/jre1.6.0_31/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so(Java_sun_print_CUPSPrinter_canConnect+0x46)[0x7f27fa84cc36]
[0x7f280118ad6e]
======= Memory map: ========
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23969795                           /opt/jre1.6.0_31/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 08:06 23969795                           /opt/jre1.6.0_31/bin/java
4010a000-42dd6000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
ac200000-100000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27e4000000-7f27e7ff9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27e7ff9000-7f27e8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27e8000000-7f27e9370000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27e9370000-7f27ec000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27ec000000-7f27efffc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27efffc000-7f27f0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27f0567000-7f27f056a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27f056a000-7f27f0668000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f27f0668000-7f27f066b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I read that problem is because lib openssl, update my libraries and error continue

Any suggestions

Thanks.

Comment: The code executing at `0x0000000040a2f3e0` is the offender. Its not CUPS or OpenSSL. What is the code doing there? Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: To clarify (and counter the previous comment), it can not be categorically stated "that it is not CUPS or OpenSSL".  But it probably is!  Because usually the call stack you see is valid (not corrupted itself) and double free's by definition mean some interaction with the libraries in question has an error (even if it was a failure to NULL out a previous memory usage that was freed). But you really need to `valgrind` the execution of the JVM :) to further expand the analysis.  The 64bit address you see is probably on the heap and part of the malloc memory allocation in question.

Comment: I will install valgrind in server for a better analysis, and post the result. thanks

Comment: Today I run valgrind  (valgrind --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full java -version) , the final line is "==18932== ERROR SUMMARY: 42543 errors from 248 contexts (suppressed: 9 from 6)" , I dont detect any error line in the log info..

Comment: I run valgrind in server, but i think my valgrind parameters don't is correct, valgrind invocation (valgrind --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full java -version) return a log information of the classes in my java installation , I don't see any reference at my java web application, call is correct or not?

Comment: Apparently solution it was improve java class responsible for printing,
in my test the problem is resolved, but i will wait for client updated for the final result.
thanks